# How to change font size for CupertinoDatePicker in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino

I need to change the font size of CupertinoDatePicker so it looks more like native one. The font is small compared to ios datepicker. 
For the height wrapping in a Container with height of `MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.height / 3` makes the height to be similar to native one.

Answer (score 27):

Another way to do this, is to wrap the `CupertinoDatePicker` in `CupertinoTheme`.

```
CupertinoTheme(
    data: CupertinoThemeData(
        textTheme: CupertinoTextThemeData(
            dateTimePickerTextStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
            ),
        ),
     ),
     child: CupertinoDatePicker(
          ...
```

Comment: if background doesn't change, you can add brightness. ```brightness: Theme.of(context).brightness,``` to CupertinoThemeData.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72496007/change-text-color-of-cupertinotimerpicker  how about this ?

Answer (score 4):

Finally got it, works as expected.

```
DefaultTextStyle.merge(
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
      child: CupertinoDatePicker(....)
)
```