# Flutter : Change Text Color CupertinoDatePicker in mode Dark Mode

Tags: flutter, dart, cupertinopicker

I have CupertinoDatePicker in my application to selected date and time with this code :

```
formatColumn(
widget: Consumer<MainCalendarProvider>(
 builder: (_, mcProvider, __) => SizedBox(
 height: sizes.height(context) / 3.5,
child: CupertinoDatePicker(
initialDateTime: result['dateRevision'],
 minimumDate: result['dateRevision'],
use24hFormat: true,
onDateTimeChanged: (dateChange) {
mcProvider.setSelectedDateFromCupertinoDatePicker(  dateChange, );},
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  title: 'Date Activity'),
```

Everything is work , until i added feature dark mode in my application. In mode dark mode text color CupertinoDatePicker still black , i want change this to white. 
In CupertinoDatePicker , only have backgroundcolor property. I already try change to Red,Blue,Green etc but the text still black.

How can i change this ?

Thank's.

[image]

Comment: Hey man, how did you manage to achieve the dark mode? Thanks!

Comment: @AngelTodorov you should save value of switch (true/false) in local storage (in my app using shared preferences). then you can use this value to toggle brightness  property in MaterialApp depend on switch value changed.

Comment: I have no issue changing light to dark and vise versa on any other part of the app but the Cupertino picker - so my question is how did you manage to change both picker backgroundColor and text color?

Comment: my bad , if you have already change brightness in MaterialApp, depending based on my project  it automatically change the background picker. Then for textColor you can follow answer in below , Wrap your picker with `CupertinoTheme`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you're missing some styles in your `Theme`, but [one of these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55050696/how-to-change-font-size-for-cupertinodatepicker-in-flutter) might do the trick!

Answer (score 28):

I guess `CupertinoTheme` gets not overridden with normal `Theme`, here's how to apply dark mode for `CupertinoDatePicker`:

```
CupertinoTheme(
    data: CupertinoThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
     ),
     child: CupertinoDatePicker(
          ...
```

Comment: Hint: Instead of "Brigtness.dark" you can use Theme.of(context).brightness so that it matches your current theme mode (light/dark).

Comment: This is the perfect solution, worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

Youll need to explicitly specify the `Brightness` to solve this problem.

#### Static Brightness Mode

Will not change when the operating system brightness mode changes

```dart
CupertinoTheme(
    data: CupertinoThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
     ),
     child: CupertinoDatePicker(
          ...
```

#### Dynamic Brightness Mode

Updates in sync with the operating system brightness mode

```
CupertinoTheme(
    data: CupertinoThemeData(
        brightness: CupertinoTheme.of(context).brightness,
     ),
     child: CupertinoDatePicker(
          ...
```

Furthermore, you can apply this theme to your entire app by specifying the data wherever the `CupertinoApp` is defined:

#### App-Wide

Define it once and have it apply to the whole app

```
CupertinoApp(
      theme: const CupertinoThemeData(
          brightness: <insertChoiceHere>,
      ...
```

Wouldnt mind if this is bumped up as the best answer, since it provides all the detail of the existing ones with a breakdown of options. :D (Trying to get my reputation up!)