# Flutter - CuppertinoDatePicker theme overwrite breaks column width

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-cupertino

I'm using the CupertinoDatePicker for setting a date in a form. To match our application design I need the picker to be in dark mode, so I adjusted the `backgroundColor`. For the text in the picker to be white I wrapped the picker inside a `Container` with a `CupertinoTheme` to set the color. I did this based on this solution: [How to change font size for CupertinoDatePicker in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55050696/how-to-change-font-size-for-cupertinodatepicker-in-flutter). For some reason this breaks the widths of the columns in the CupertinoDatePicker, and I don't have a clue why that's happening. If I remove the `CupertinoTheme` the columns are fine but the text is dark too, thus unreadable.

Code:

```
void showPlatformDatePicker() {
  showCupertinoModalPopup(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) => Container(
      color: Colors.black87,
      height: 400,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(18, 18, 18, 1),
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: Text(
                'Done',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 350,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: CupertinoTheme(
              data: CupertinoThemeData(
                textTheme: CupertinoTextThemeData(
                  dateTimePickerTextStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
                mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                maximumDate: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 365)),
                initialDateTime:
                    DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 365 * 18)),
                onDateTimeChanged: (val) {
                  final date = val.toIso8601String();
                  context
                      .bloc<FormBloc>()
                      .add(DateChanged(date));
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely, adding a `fontSize`to the `CupertinoTextThemeData` fixes this issue:

```dart
Container(
            height: 350,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: CupertinoTheme(
              data: CupertinoThemeData(
                textTheme: CupertinoTextThemeData(
                  dateTimePickerTextStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
                mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                maximumDate: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 365)),
                initialDateTime:
                    DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 365 * 18)),
                onDateTimeChanged: (val) {
                  final date = val.toIso8601String();
                  context
                      .bloc<FormBloc>()
                      .add(DateChanged(date));
                },
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Try using this code

You can edit it according to your requirement

```
Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
                    child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                      initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                      onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime nowDate) {
                        var currentTime = nowDate;
                      },
                      use24hFormat: true,
                      minimumYear: 2010,
                      maximumYear: 2018,
                      minuteInterval: 1,
                      mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.dateAndTime,
                    ),
                  );
```

Comment: What in your code example is supposed to make a difference compared to my initial code except for the fact you're picking the `dateAndTime` mode. I don't really need that mode, hence why I picked `date`.