# Custom CupertinoDatePicker Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to make a CupertinoDatePicker like this:

[image]

But I can't change anything except the Background.

I found an answer like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57830696/16864379

Here's what I got:

[image]

But which parameter is responsible for the active color to make it pink?
And what parameter is responsible for removing the translucent white backing?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the CupertinoDatePicker's text and active text use same `TextStyle`,so can't just change the active color but change both.

```dart
return itemPositioningBuilder(
            context,
            Text(
              localizations.datePickerHour(displayHour),
              semanticsLabel: localizations.datePickerHourSemanticsLabel(displayHour),
              style: _themeTextStyle(context, isValid: _isValidHour(selectedAmPm, index)),
            ),
          );
```

```dart
TextStyle _themeTextStyle(BuildContext context, { bool isValid = true }) {
  final TextStyle style = CupertinoTheme.of(context).textTheme.dateTimePickerTextStyle;
  return isValid ? style : style.copyWith(color: CupertinoDynamicColor.resolve(CupertinoColors.inactiveGray, context));
}
```

- change both color

```dart
CupertinoTheme(
              data: CupertinoThemeData(
                textTheme: CupertinoTextThemeData(
                  dateTimePickerTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.pink),
                ),
              ),
              child: CupertinoDatePicker(onDateTimeChanged: (_) {}),
            )
```